# How to get the number of open file descriptors?

Tags: perl

How to find number of files opened by my Perl program? Of course, I could use something like

```
scalar( my @a = glob "/proc/$$/fd/*" );
```

but it looks a bit hacky... I should have overlooked something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question to that here 
[How to find open global filehandles in a perl program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845949/how-to-find-open-global-filehandles-in-a-perl-program)

You will need to change it a bit to suit your requirements

Comment: The selected answer there has the code from my question... Looks like case closed.

Comment: Glad to be of some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan all possible file handles from 0 to to getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE) using either `fstat()` call or `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` call.

However, using any of these will be significantly slower than simply looking at `/proc/self/fd/*`. And, they still depend on some Linux'isms and do not make your program portable.

Answer (score -1):

you could use lsof to for that eg. lsof /|wc -l should work fine

Comment: AFAIK `lsof` uses /proc/*/fd internally, so it's generally the same... Oh and I need files open by _this_ process, not everyone else.